# Exclusive NFT per smart contract in SOLIDITY

Tags: solidity, nft

I want to mint only one exclusive NFT per smart contract. All tutorials and books shows how to make collectables through inheritance of ERC721. So the simple code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

    contract SimpleCollectible is ERC721 {

      uint256 public tokenCounter;
      constructor () public ERC721 ("Dogie", "DOG"){
        tokenCounter = 0;
      }
      function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
        return newItemId;
      }
    }
```

How restrict minting to 1 piece of art?

Comment: You can create a storage variable as a boolean, and once someone mints it, set it to  true, then you can check if said variable is true for the next minting attempts with a `require`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to tokenCounter. You could use the following:

```
function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI) public returns(uint256) {
    require(tokenCounter == 0, "error msg here");
    uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
    tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    return newItemId;
  }
```

In fact, there are tons of ways of achieving the same result. Maybe you could use a simple boolean to save a little bit on gas.

I hope you fin this useful :)